# Eigen vector matrix right division issue

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, division, eigen

I am trying to perform right division in c++ on a vector/matrix as is done in matlab with the / operator.
More specifically, I am using eigen and the code snippet where I try to do the division is the following:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
// Do stuff
// ...
Vector3d instance;
Vector3d mu;
Matrix3d covar;
int dimensionality;
// do stuff initialize here
// Calculate cholesky decomposition
Eigen::Matrix3d normTransform(dimensionality, dimensionality);
Eigen::LLT<Eigen::Matrix3d> cholSolver(covar);
if (cholSolver.info()==Eigen::Success) 
    normTransform = cholSolver.matrixL();
else {
Eigen::SelfAdjointEigenSolver<Eigen::Matrix3d> eigenSolver(covar);
normTransform = eigenSolver.eigenvectors()
               * eigenSolver.eigenvalues().cwiseSqrt().asDiagonal();
}
RowVector3d difference = instance - mu;

difference.transpose().array() * normTransform.inverse().array();
//YOU_MIXED MATRIXES OF DIFFERENT SIZES
difference.array() * normTransform.inverse().array();
//YOU_MIXED MATRIXES OF DIFFERENT SIZES
difference.array() / normTransform.array();
//YOU_MIXED MATRIXES OF DIFFERENT SIZES
etc..
```

The Row vector is a 3X1 vector and the normTransform is a 3X3 matrix.
I cannot get my head around how the operation should be performed.

Any clues what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Panos.

Comment: Fixed it. Apparently I was thinking too complicated . A simple

    RowVector3d adsf = difference * normTransform.inverse();

did the trick

Comment: Would you mind rewording the comment as an [answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the suggestion of Avi, I put my comment as an answer so that the question is closed.
Fixed it. Apparently I was thinking too complicated . A simple

```
RowVector3d adsf = difference * normTransform.inverse();
```

did the trick